# Why are we allowed to substitute a value into a system of equations when we don't know that that value is part of the solution set?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working through [Jim Hefferon's Linear Algebra](https://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf). I was working on question 1.30 which reads as follows:

> Prove that, where $a, b, c, d, e$ are real numbers with $a \ne 0$, if the linear equation
> $ax + by = c$ has the same solution set as $ax + dy = e$ then they are the same equation. What if $a = 0$?

I attempted this problem for hours, but I was getting nowhere and ended up looking at the solution. The solution involves solving for $x$ in terms of $y$, which I understand is only possible because $a \ne 0$, and substituting a value of $y=0$. Why are we allowed to substitute a value of $y=0$ in this system of equations? How do we know that $y=0$ is part of the solution set of the system of equations? Is it the case that we're allowed to substitute any value we want in a system of equations so long as it doesn't cause a contradiction or division by $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, both equations provide a single solution $(x,y)$ *for every* value of $y$, because the steps that lead to
$$x=\frac{c-by}a$$
are reversible.

So, both equations will have a unique solution of the form $(x_0,0)$ (i.e. when $y=0$), and thus the two values for $x_0$ must coincide by the hypothesis.

Comment: So, as long as $y=0$ does not cause a division by $0$ or a contradiction of the problem statement, then we can substitute $0$? Could we also substitute $x=0$ in this equation (I'm guessing we can but that it won't get us anywhere since we don't know that $b \ne 0$ or that $d  \ne 0$)?

Comment: exactly. if you have a linear equation like $a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n=b$ and if $a_1\not =0$ then you can subsitute any number you want to $x_2,...,x_n$, there is always an $x_1$ which make this a solution set

Comment: Thank you! @ali